# useEffect not tracking a useState dependency properly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I have a button and an input box where upon submitting the input, a search will be run on the searchTerm and a table of results is displayed. I put the searchTerm as a dependency inside useEffect() so that the search will only be run if the searchTerm changes. Since useEffect() gets run when the window is opened, I added a check to see if searchTerm > 0 so the search is not performed when the window is opened.

However by doing this, the **table rows are not updated upon the first search but the second search**. If I remove the `if (searchTerm.length > 0)` check, the table will populate as expected on first search (although it will run a search on the empty searchTerm right away which isn't ideal).

```
export const SearchWindow: React.FC<Props> = props => {

    const documentationIndexState = useSelector((store: StoreState) => store.documentationIndex);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = React.useState(''); // value inside input box
    const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = React.useState(''); // term to search (set once search clicked)

    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log('in useEffect with searchTerm len: ' + searchTerm.length);
        if (searchTerm.length > 0) {
            console.log('len > 0, running search');
            getSearchResults(props.config, searchTerm, documentationIndexState, dispatch).then(async searchResults => {
                const rows = searchResults.map(result => {
                    return {
                        cells: {
                            source: documentationIndexState.headerReference.find(x => x.id === result.id)!.source,
                        },
                    };
                });
                dispatch(setSearchResults(rows));
            });
        }
    }, [searchTerm]); // Only run search if searchTerm changes

    return (
        <div>
            <form>
                <input
                    placeholder='Enter Search Term'
                    onChange={e => setSearchInput(e.target.value)}
                    value={searchInput}
                />
                <button
                    onClick={e => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        setSearchTerm(searchInput);
                    }}
                >
                    Search
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <DataTable
            rows={documentationIndexState.searchResults}
        />
        ...
```

Comment: So you want to run it once on load so the table gets populated?

Comment: i only want to run the search which then populates the table if the user types an input and then clicks the search button.

Comment: This part of the code is strange: `getSearchResults(props.config, searchTerm, documentationIndexState, dispatch).then(async searchResults =>.`  It is weird to call a plain function and pass dispatch as an argument.  Probably that should be a thunk that you dispatch. https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-logic-thunks

Comment: Your `useEffect` definitely has some missing dependencies like `documentationIndexState` and `props.config`, but just adding those as dependencies will create other problems.

Comment: Consider having a `useCallback` that runs the search and calls `dispatch`. It should be your `onClick`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up adding a `if (searchTerm.length === 0)` check to inside the `getSearchResults()` method and had it return `[]` if true instead of checking len before entering the search method.

Answer (score 1):

The callback for your search button should execute the search.

```js
function Form() {
  const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = React.useState('');
  const runSearch = React.useCallback(
    () => {
      console.info('Searching', searchInput)
    },
    [searchInput]
  );

  return (
    <form>
      <h1> The form! </h1>
      <input
        placeholder='Enter Search Term'
        onChange={e => setSearchInput(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={runSearch}
      >
        Search
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}
ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById('app')
).render(
    React.createElement(Form)
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app">
</div>
```

Comment: this solution did not work, but this does make sense (i think the code is a bit convoluted further down the line)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

```js
const [loaded, setLoaded] = React.useState(false);
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!loaded) {
        setLoaded(true);
        return;
    }
    console.log('in useEffect with searchTerm len: ' + searchTerm.length);
    if (searchTerm.length > 0) {
        console.log('len > 0, running search');
        getSearchResults(props.config, searchTerm, documentationIndexState, dispatch).then(async searchResults => {
            const rows = searchResults.map(result => {
                return {
                    cells: {
                        source: documentationIndexState.headerReference.find(x => x.id === result.id)!.source,
                    },
                };
            });
            dispatch(setSearchResults(rows));
        });
    }
}, [searchTerm]); // Only run search if searchTerm changes & loaded is true
```